# How to insert more than one record from visualforce page to custom object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dml, insert

I want to insert the records in a custom object. The code is working fine when I insert one record at a time but when I am trying to insert more than one record on a same run one at a time than it is giving exception INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call
can anyone help?

```
<apex:page controller="myclass" docType="html-5.0">
<apex:form >


Product Name: <apex:input type="text" id="name" value="{!value}"/><br/>
Product Category: <apex:input type="text" id="cat" value="{!value2}"/><br/>
Product Status: <apex:input type="text" id="status" value="{!value3}"/><br/>

<apex:commandButton action="{!insertRecords}" value="INSERT RECORDS" rerender="theForm"/>   
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>



public class myclass {

    opportunityProduct__c op= new opportunityProduct__c();

    public string value { get; set;}
    public string value2 { get; set;}
    public string value3 { get; set;}
//String [] arrayOfProducts = new String[] {'Shavings','Bins/ Containers','others','fee'};


    public void insertRecords(){
       // value = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('inpval1');
        //value2 = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('inpval2');
        //value3 = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('inpval3');
        system.debug(value + value2+ value3);
        op.Prod_name__c= value;
        op.Prod_type__c=value2;
         insert op;
        value='';
        value2='';
      system.debug('record inserted' + op); 
  //  for (Integer i=0; i<arrayOfProducts.size(); i++) {   
   //if(arrayOfProducts[i].equalsIgnoreCase(value2) && ((!value3.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed won') && (!value3.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed lost'))) ){
     // insert op;
      //system.debug('record inserted' + op); 
        //}                
        //else{
        //system.debug('Category not predefined. Record with a new type inserted. ' + op); 
        //arrayOfProducts[arrayOfProducts.size()]=value2;
        //insert op;
          // }
            //}    
      if ( value3.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed won') || value3.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed lost'))
      system.debug('Opportunity is in stage Closed Won or Closed Lost.');

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with below code is:-

```
for (Integer i=0; i<arrayOfProducts.size(); i++) {   
    if(arrayOfProducts[i].equalsIgnoreCase(value2) && ((!value3.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed won') && (!value3.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed lost'))) ){
       insert op;
    }                
    else{
       arrayOfProducts[arrayOfProducts.size()]=value2;
       insert op;
    }
}
```

The above code will fail because:-

1. You have defined opportunityProduct__c instance at the beginning of your code as:-`opportunityProduct__c op= new opportunityProduct__c();` You are running the loop and trying to insert the same instance every time. when loop run for the first row in array, **op** gets inserted and it will get assigned with a record id. when loop runs for second row, you are again inserting op which have an ID.

Note:- A record with an ID cannot be re-inserted and hence you are getting exception INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call

2. Do not write a dml statement inside for loop. You may hit the apex governor limit. You can take advantage of List to avoid it.

Your code should look something like this:-

```
List<opportunityProduct__c> oplist =new List<opportunityProduct__c>();
        for (Integer i=0; i<arrayOfProducts.size(); i++) {   
            if(arrayOfProducts[i].equalsIgnoreCase(value2) && ((!value3.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed won') && (!value3.equalsIgnoreCase('Closed lost'))) ){
                oplist.add(new opportunityProduct__c(Prod_name__c=value));
            }
        }  
        insert oplist;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `insert op;` the system populates the `Id` of the new `OpportunityProduct` in that sObject variable.

If you'd like to reuse that variable as a container for another record to insert, you need to reinitialize it to remove that `Id` value and database identity:

```
opportunityProduct__c op= new opportunityProduct__c();
```

However, it's much better practice instead to accumulate a `List<OpportunityProduct>` and insert them all in a single operation, saving DML limits usage:

```
List<OpportunityProduct> opsToInsert = new List<OpportunityProduct>();

if (someLogic) {
    opsToInsert.add(
        new OpportunityProduct(
            Product2Id = ...,
            ...
        )
    );
}
// Potentially other logic to add more records to `opsToInsert`.
// ...
// Then, lastly,
insert opsToInsert;
```